# After updating to Fabric Crashlytics sometimes natives crashes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, crashlytics, google-fabric

After last update of Crashlytics with Fabric native app is crashing some times (Tested on nexus 6 with Android 7.1.1)

What I see in Google Play Console is this.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.<init> (Kit.java:45)
  at com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.<init> (Answers.java:20)
  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init> (Crashlytics.java:29)
  at funler.com.funler.FunlerApplication.onCreate (FunlerApplication.java:27)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1007)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1256)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

of course at `funler.com.funler.FunlerApplication.onCreate (FunlerApplication.java:27)`

I have

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

I found something related to `MultiDex.install(this)` been the issue, but I don't have that in my code. 
Also saw something related to `dexOptions`, not sure what to do.

The big issue is that I cant reproduce it as wanted, trying in device it happens ~1 very 20 times.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

ext {
        versionSdk = 25

        major = 3
        minor = 2
        patch = 5
}

def generateVersionCode(){

        return ext.versionSdk * 1000000 +
                        ext.major * 10000 +
                        ext.minor * 100 +
                        ext.patch;
}

android {

        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
                applicationId .
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 25
                versionCode generateVersionCode()
                versionName "${project.ext.major}.${project.ext.minor}.${project.ext.patch}"
                multiDexEnabled true

                .
        }
        productFlavors {
                .
        }
        buildTypes {
                .
        }
        dexOptions {
                jumboMode = true
        }
}


dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
        compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
        compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev112-1.19.0') {
                exclude(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305')
        }
        compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc') {
                exclude(module: 'jsr305')
        }
        compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.7'
        compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:22.52.561.4'
        compile files('libs/MobileAppTracker-3.9.jar')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
                transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
        provided files('amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
}

configurations {
        compile.exclude module: 'jsr305'
}

buildscript {
        repositories {
                maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
                classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
        maven {
                url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
        }
}
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                                details.useVersion '25.4.0'
                        }
                }
        }
}
...
```

Comment: Use Build -> Clean Project before run, some times that issue really annoying

Comment: That happends in the live build. You think that could be fixed the same way?

Comment: Are you importing the Crashlytics and Fabric libraries into the file where you're calling `Fabric.with`?

Comment: I have import `io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;` and `import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;` In that file, and it works 95 % of the times

Comment: Hmmm very odd that it's happening so infrequently. Any chance you can share your build.gradle?

Comment: Sure added build.grundle

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'm not seeing a clear root cause unfortunately as your build.gradle looks correct. Are there other devices or OS' that this is happening on? Also, do you have any conditional logic around implementing Fabric in the app?

Comment: I dont have anything more then that Fabric Init no logic extra what so ever, thing is that it crashes every 10/20 times... not easy to reproduce

Comment: @MartinPage, have you found a solutions for this issue? I have exactly the same issue with a class that is part of library that my company has developed and I use in my app. In my case it usually happens when upgrading the app (overriding the APK with a newer one), while the "problematic" class may exist in both app versions (it happens both when upgrading from an old app version without this class and when upgrading from a new version that contains this class).

Comment: No I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by code minification (obfuscation).
If you're using proguard (and the issue occurred on release builds), 
You might want to check out if some library that you are using requires some proguard rules to be added manually.

Best of luck.